# Are websites now considered answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged an answer to a [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/program-browser-extension-to-analyze-the-impact-of-each-browser-extension-on-g) that was requesting a "program or browser extension".

Instead of providing a recommendation for a program or browser extension, the answer consists of just a single sentence that points to a website.

I flagged the question as "not an answer" because that flag should be used when:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

The flag was declined and the inappropriate answer remains.  (Note that I just flagged the answer as "Low Quality", but I think "Not an Answer" fits even better.)

Since the question specifically asks for a "program or browser extension" (and thus not a website or even a web-app), the answer provided does not answer the question asked.  Thus, it's more or less okay as a comment, but not as an answer.

I guess we can debate whether or not a website is really a program, but that opens Pandora's box.  We could further expand the definition of a web-app to almost any website (although we've already concluded we don't want websites as answers), but the question author did not ask for a web-app.

Are we now allowing links to websites as answers, even when the question specifically asks for a "program or browser extension"?

Comment: I guess I'll post a similar question geared toward websites when [Website recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations?referrer=AQx0849qiZ8aDHio0gR48w2) gets opened :-)

Answer (score 3):

I **do not** think we should allow websites to act as "software" or "browser extensions". In this case, I agree with you completely, this is not an answer and as the OP said,

> I am looking for a **program or browser extension** ...

Having said this, if the OP did not say "program" or "browser extension" and based possibly on how the question was worded, a website (web app) may possibly be considered software in that case, but here it's clearly not that.

Comment: RockpaperLizard flagged it NAA initially but the flag was declined (as stated above). So he could not flag it again for the same reason, which is why it <s>is</s> was flagged LQ currently.

Comment: @Izzy My bad (made an edit), do you think that this is NAA?

Comment: Your answer here? No, that's fine. The post in question? See [my Meta answer here](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2548/185) ;)

Comment: @Izzy Just FYI, your link will not work because StackExchange *still* does not allow HTTPS for meta sites.  I reported this issue recently in a meta, so you may be able to find the QA discussing it.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Strange, as it works for me. Yes, there's some trouble with that certificate, as `*.stackexchange.com` doesn't match `*.*.stackexchange.com` (long standing issue) – but once you've told the browser to ignore that, no more warnings :)

Comment: @Izzy LOL.  *"Once you've told the browser to ignore that..."*  My friend, you've just earned yourself your very first facepalm!  Well, by me, at least!  LOL :-)  :-)  :-)  I'm still smiling! :-)

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Are you saying you didn't know you can add exceptions for this? :) Now it's me who's LOLing :)

Comment: @Izzy No, I'm saying that while my eyes were shut due to the impact of my palm smacking my forehead, I started to imagine some of the possible exploit vectors.  :-)

Comment: OK, getting OT now. But while agreeing the solution isn't that nice, I don't think it's that dangerous either – and be it just for the fact that otherwise SE wouldn't have https available for Meta sites ;)

Answer (score 1):

While it may be arguable if the post can be counted as an answer, I see it as something between NAA and LQ: It definitely doesn't match the requirement listed. Usually in such cases, one would post a comment on the question asking if it is acceptable though; but you cannot do this with 1 rep.

Solution: I've converted the post into a comment (it makes a very good comment), leaving it to Franck to decide – and leaving a message to the answerer he's welcome to post a new answer meeting our quality guidelines if Franck indicates such.

Answer (score -2):

I think the NAA flag should only be used for posts that don’t *try* to answer the question. For example:

- *I need this, too. Anyone knows a solution?*
- *The program recommended by Bob does not work.*
- *What do you mean with "should allow collaboration"?*

If the post is some kind of answer, even if it’s a bad one (e.g., ignoring OP’s requirements), that flag should not be used. Deciding if a NAA flag is valid should not require the mod to check OP’s requirements and evaluate if the answer meets them; it should be decidable without even reading OP’s question.

If the answer does not meet OP’s requirements, we should comment and downvote.